# Trying to Convert a string to another string from array in a file on only the first space

Tags: java, arrays, stringtokenizer

Disclaimer, I've been at java for about a month.  I'm completely lost on this.  I'm trying to have a user input a phrase and if any strings in that phrase is found on the array, it returns the corresponding string in one line.  if the string isn't found, it would just skip it.

so if someone typed in "dog eat my fish"

and the array holds:
dog perro
eat munched
fish yellow trout

it would return:
perro munched yellow trout

I haven't written the code to print out what I've got yet, but I know this code isn't working.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws java.io.IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userString = " ";
        userString = englishString();       

        String[][] wordList = new String[10][2];
        loadEnglishString(wordList);

    }
    public static String englishString() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String s1 = " ";
        System.out.println("Please enter a phrase to translate: ");
        s1 = input.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();

        return s1;
    }



    public static void loadEnglishString(String[][] wordList)  
        throws java.io.IOException {
        String filName = " ";       
        filName = ("/home/chrism/ArrayTest2.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filName));  
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                boolean stop = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
                    if(stop)
                        break;
                    for(int j = 0; j < wordList[i].length; j++) 
                        if(input.hasNextLine())
                            wordList[i][j] = input.nextLine();
                        else {
                            stop = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        input.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Questions: why you have two-dimensional array declared? `String[][] wordList = new String[10][2];` ?

Comment: You will have to explain what is the problem you are seeing, if there is an error or exception, then the relevant message or the stack trace.

Comment: you mean when the inputed value will find out if that value is existing in array and remove it ?

Comment: I have the 2d array declared for the txt file that contains the list of words and their conversion output.  the issue is when i try to run, it gets stuck. and if the value exists... it will need to print out the corresponding value.  thanks for the help thus far

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want to change your `for` loop. Brackets are your friend.

```
for(int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
    if(stop)
        break;
    for(int j = 0; j < wordList[i].length; j++) {
        if(input.hasNextLine())
            wordList[i][j] = input.nextLine();
        else {
            stop = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The way you had it, both increments were registering as dead code because your second break would always called the first time through the loop, and your `else` was registering as coupled with the first `if(stop)`.

Edit: don't know for sure about how the else would couple, but the break is definitely called after the first run through.

Answer (score 0):

//package com.myjava.stokenizerr;

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class MyStringTokenizer {

    public static void main(String a[]){

/* your code for user input string */
/* assume input as dog eat my fish */

        String input = "dog eat my fish";
        String msg = "dog perro eat munched fish yellow trout";
        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(msg," ");
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(input," ");
        while(st1.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(st1.nextToken()); // Store this one(first) string array 
        }
    while(st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(st2.nextToken());   // Store in another(second) array
        }
        /* Now Compare both the arrays */
        /* If the strings are equal then remove string from second array */\
        /* If equal just skip it */
   }
}
```

See the above code st1.nextToken() and st2.Tokens() will give you the values 
For comparing take two loops

```
 for(i==0;i<array1length();i++) {  

 for(j==0;j<array2length();j++) { 
      // Your code for comparsion
    }
  }
```

Comment: You said you are practising java from one month then go in a Simple way like
In Array1 you have = "dog perro eat munched fish yellow trout"
For user input you can break the string into tokens and store it in Array2
Then compare both the Arrays